# Rank of Jacobian for injective functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Consider the smooth, injective function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^M$ where $N < M$. Let $J:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ be the Jacobian of $f$.

Is it true that $f$ being injective $\implies$ that $J(x)$ must have full rank $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ for which $J(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: The Jacobian of a smooth function $f : \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^M$ at a point $x \in \mathbb R^N$ would typically be a linear map $J_x : \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^M$ representing the best linear approximation of $f$ near $x$. The function $\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^{M\times N}$ given by $x\mapsto J_x$ is not generally linear, so it does not make sense to talk about rank. You may want to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. I've added in that I mean to ask if the Jacobian matrix evaluated for any particular $x$ is guaranteed to have full column rank.

Comment: No, it is not true. Consider $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^n$ (for any $n\geq 1$ you like), $f(x)=(x^3,0)$. Then, $f$ is injective, but $f’(x)=(3x^2,0)$ vanishes when $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo, I've added the condition that we are interested in the column rank of $J(x)$  $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ for which $J(x)\neq 0$ to make it a bit more interesting.

Comment: Still no. Look at $f(x,y)=(x^3,y^3,0)$. Then, $f'(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}3x^2&0\\0&3y^2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $f$ is injective, but the rank is $0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$, the rank is $1$ when $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$ or viceversa, and it is $2$ otherwise. Injectivity alone doesn't force conditions on the rank.

Comment: What *is* true (since $N<M$) is that if the Jacobian has rank $N$ at $x$, then $f$ *is* injective on a neighborhood of $x$.